# Datepicker doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport'/>
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker</title>

  <link type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/css/sunny/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

  <script scrc="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h3>Date of Birth</h3>
  <input type="text" name="birth_date" id="datepicker">
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#datepicker').datepicker();
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why this doesn't work ? tried several times but get the same error in debug:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'.

Comment: It seems that you didn't include datepicker.js and jquery-ui library.

Comment: i think there is versioning problem in jquery.js and jquery-ui..just include their latest releases.

Comment: Are you using jQuery 1.6?? If yes then I am not sure whether it supports date picker or not. Update jQuery plugin at least 1.7.2 and it will work http://jsfiddle.net/dimomohit/2js1cykh/. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo here

```
<script scrc="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
---------^
```

`scrc` should be changed to `src`

```
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. It was indeed a typo. Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

try this fiddle [**Demo - here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3sb7go1h/) , in your code check the included scripts are loaded properly, or check the console any error showing

```
<link type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/css/sunny/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

  <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
</head>
```